# Jquery - Enable an editorFor text field on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an editorFor that starts off disabled that looks like this

```
 @Html.EditorFor(job => j.serialNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = true} })
```

Then below that I have an edit button that looks like this

```
<input id="edit@(j.serialNumber)" type="button" class="noprint btn btn-primary" value="Edit" onclick="enableEdit('@(j.serialNumber)')" />
```

This calls my enableEdit method that currently looks like this

```
 function enableEdit(serialNumber) {
       
  }
```

What do I have to add to the method in order to enable the 'EditorFor' textbox?

Comment: can you show html generated code for `@Html.EditorFor(job =..` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id of the EditorFor element this way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(job => j.serialNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "my-editor", disabled = true} })
```

Then, in your method you can select it by jquery and set the disabled prop.

```
$("#my-editor").prop("disabled", false);
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/